# Why doesn't the char convert to an int?

Tags: c++

Please tell me why this c++ code doesn't work, I get ] in the output when i enter in an equation such as 2+4... Why is this happening?:

```c++
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input;
    int length;
    int p1;
    int i1;
    int i2;
    string result;

    cout << "Enter your expression" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    length = input.size();

    char data[length];
    input.copy( data, length );

    switch (data[1]){
        case '+' : 
            p1 = length - 2;
            i1 = data[0];
            i2 = data[p1];
            result = i1 + i2;

            cout << result << endl;
            break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this isn't javascript...

Comment: seems like you're missing `atoi(result)` or some such method that converts the char to an int.

Comment: @Dunno Why would you think this is supposed to be JavaScript? It's tagged as C++.

Comment: The char `'1'` (for example) does *not* convert directly to the int `1`, but rather the ASCII value `49`.

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek deadpan jab at JavaScript for implicitly converting anything into anything else with often "funny" results.

Comment: Additionally, this code is buggy. `2+4` has a length of 4, right? (being null-terminated) so the `p1 = length - 2` would essentially point to `+` right?

On top of that, basically it only works for single-digit parameters.

Comment: Also, it's probably not a good idea to rely on string positions for numbers/operators.  What if I wanted to calculate "10+1" or "2 + 3" (with spaces)?  Or what if I have a typo: "1++1", etc.

Comment: I would be surprised if this code does what you expect it to do. There are two main error. As everybody points out, converting char to `int` is not straight forward but you need `atoi`, then, you always look for the `+` at the same place....

Comment: @apalomer -- converting **`char`** to `int` is trivial: `ch - '0'` always works (assuming `ch` in fact is one of the character values '0'..'9').

Comment: @0x5453 My knowledge of c++ is limited, I'm learning, I don't know how else to do do this, other than using the position of the numbers operator etc... :(  I was planning on adding more cases for other operators and more switches for larger equations...

Comment: @nopeismanamebro It's fine; that's how everybody starts out.  Just keep at it.  Get your simple case working first and then see if you can figure out different ways to expand your application and make it more robust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three things confusing you here.

First the expressions:

```
i1 = data[0];
i2 = data[p1];
```

Assign the character values of `data[0]` and `data[p1]` 
If the input is `2+4` you're actually assigning the character values of '2' and '+'. In ASCII "2" is represented by code-point 50 and "+" by 43.

So then the expression `i1+i2` actually equals 93.

What is also confusing you is that `s=i1+i2` actually binds to the overloading `basic_string& operator=( CharT ch );` and so converts 93 back to a character and assigns a singleton string to `s` which happens to be `]` as you see!

This is your code with those three faults fixed:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string input;
    int length;
    int p1;
    int i1;
    int i2;
    string result;

    cout << "Enter your expression" << endl;
    cin >> input;
    length = input.size();

    char data[length];
    input.copy( data, length );

    switch(data[1]){
    case '+' : p1 = length - 1; //Not -2 as was.
    i1 = data[0]-'0';//Works for ASCII compatible and so all modern systems...
    i2 = data[p1]-'0';
    result = std::to_string(i1 + i2);//Force the creation of a decimal string of the result.
    cout << result << endl;
    break;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I tried to build and run it, but it says to_string is not a member of std

Comment: @nopeismanamebro Are you using something pre-C++11 that's when `std::to_string()` went in.

Comment: @nopeismanamebro codeblocks supports various compilers. Do you know what compiler you have installed?

Comment: It Shows that i have MinGW

Comment: You may need to set a compiler option. I don't know much about MinGW may be worth searching Stackoverflow or raising a question.
Otherwise you'll need to implement `to_string` yourself.